# Vert.x Gradle multi module build

Tags: build, gradle, installation, multi-module, vert.x

Both Vert.x and Gradle are quite new for me. I'm familiar with basics and Hello World demos. I'm looking for guidelines to set up multi module build.

Requirements for the project:

- dependencies are managed on top level (not in each module)
- all modules are located in same level (no sub modules)
- module properties are managed in one place (eg. version & groupId/owner is defined once for the whole project)
- there is one starter module which is responsible for loading all verticles from other modules (thus there are dependencies between modules)
- single (executable) fat jar is produced as build result
- build should produce needed files to import project to the IDE (eg. Eclipse)
- different languages can be used for development (Java, Scala, JS, etc.)

I did some testing with [vertx-gradle-template](https://github.com/vert-x/vertx-gradle-template) and [vertx-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/darylteo/vertx-gradle-plugin). Neither of them is good fit for my requirements.

Comment: We ended up writing our own solution which generates a top level build.gradle and other files to cover for the needs that you describe. Its not open. Other hints are that artifactory plugin does not like to be included multiple times :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar project and I chose [vertx-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/jponge/vertx-gradle-plugin). It just groups several useful pugins.

I use this structure:

```
root-folder
 ├── app
 ├── build.gradle
 ├── settings.gradle
 ├── service 1
 ├── service 2
```

- Service 1/2 are my differents modules
- app is a module to assemble everything. It uses the plugin above and so contains the main verticle. It depends on service 1/2. The configuration of the distribution jar is here too.
- settings.gradle and build.gradle is used to centralize the versions and declare the different modules